# How to show address of search suggestion in MapboxPanelController

Tags: mapbox-ios

by implementation of search panel with MapboxSearchController, I can't show the address of suggested objects.
The code looks like this:

```
    final class SearchPanelExample: UIViewController {
    private let searchController = MapboxSearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController.delegate = self
    }
}
extension SearchPanelExample: SearchControllerDelegate {
    func categorySearchResultsReceived(category: SearchCategory, results: [SearchResult]) {
        //code, to show results
    }

    func searchResultSelected(_ searchResult: SearchResult) {
        //code, to show results
    }

    func userFavoriteSelected(_ userFavorite: FavoriteRecord) {
        //code, to show results
    }
}
```

And here is the UI:

[image: search suggestions]

I appreciate any help